max-id of mcTableStyle in MadCap Flare
I am very new to Flare and I want to ask what is the max-id in mcTableStyle. What happens if it is changed to a higher or lower number? What does this max id mean?
mcTableStyle
{
name: XXXX;
border-collapse: collapse;
border-left-style: solid;
.....
max-id: 11;
}

